# why is my search function return an error Related Field got invalid lookup: category

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

My search function works fine but it throws me an error every time i try to search an existence post in my website. when i deleted **ForeignKey** in the Question model under **category** field the error is gone. please how can i filter that category that have a **ForeignKey**

the error:

```
FieldError at /index/
Related Field got invalid lookup: category
```

my models:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)


class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    body = RichTextField(blank=False, null=False) 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(Question, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

the views:

```
def index(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', None)
    list_of_question = Question.objects.all()
    if query is not None:
        list_of_question = Question.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=query) |
            Q(category__category__icontains=query)
        )
    unread_notifications = Notification.objects.filter(user=request.user, is_read=False).count()

    paginator = Paginator(list_of_question, per_page=1)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'unread_notifications':unread_notifications,'list_of_question':list_of_question, 'paginator':paginator})
```

my form:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
        <input placeholder="Search By Category" type="text" class="form-control" name="q">
    </form>
```

Comment: It's `category__name__icontains`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter with `category__…` this means that the rest of the filter should deal with fields of a `Category` model, and a `Category` has a `name` field, so you filter with:

```
list_of_question = Question.objects.filter(
    Q(title__icontains=query) |
    Q(category__name__icontains=query)
)
```